# Why do tests fail on Travis but pass locally for this octopus build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

On Travis, here is build with Rails 5 beta 3 that fails: https://travis-ci.org/thiagopradi/octopus/jobs/114336625 .  But if I clone repo and run tests locally per the [instructions in octopus](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus) all tests are green.  Is it that the local tests are somehow not using Rails 5 beta 3, and if so, how do I get them to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually because of the way the project is setup, you can issue the following command to run with a specific rails version:

```
appraisal rails42 rake
```

where `rails42` is the particular rails version listed in the gemfiles directory of that project.